# how to fix "Could not get any response"?

Tags: flask, postman

i'm trying to call my api flask on postman or on google chrome  and i always get this:

 POSTMAN :

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to 192.168.1.178:5000/.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

Google chrome

```
Ce site est inaccessible
192.168.1.178 a mis trop de temps à répondre.
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with your flask server or could be related to the authentication method or missing data in your request.

What you can do is use the [Postman Console](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/debugging-and-logs/#network-calls-with-postman-console) to debug your outgoing request to the server.
What you can look for is:

- Check the URL (in your case I think it's an IP address) of the request
- Check the request method, for eg. 'GET', 'POST' - you might be calling the request with the wrong method.
- Check the authentication method and credentials
- Check the request body and headers.
- And so on.. make sure you fulfill all the requirements of a complete request.

You can also put `print` statements in your flask server and see if the endpoints are being called (if it's a local server).

Comment: i checked all this but the problem is when i put "print" i notice that the endpoints are not called

Comment: @LOF Maybe your endpoints are incorrectly setup? You'll need to debug your server in this case. Check your routes etc. Check the name of your functions for spelling etc.

But in any case, server should've thrown 404. This error in postman is stating that your server isn't available. Do you need some kind of proxy etc. to work with this?